# Azkaban Execute error

Tags: azkaban

Got following Error when Executing flow.

```
Error submitting flow bar. azkaban.executor.ExecutorManagerException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:10000 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I changed some lines in azkaban.properties.

```
default.timezone.id=Asia/Tokyo
jetty.port=8081
executor.port=10000
```

[azkaban](https://github.com/azkaban/azkaban) using azkaban-solo-server.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the azkaban-web-server is not able to contact the azkaban-exec-server. The azkaban executor is a separate process from the azkaban web interface and uses a separate configuration.
Firstly, confirm that the executor is running and listening on the correct port. eg. for a non-windows environment:

```
$ ps -elf | grep azkaban-exec-server
```

If it's not running, then it will need to be started. If it is running, then you need to ensure that the listening port of the executor is the same as the executor port configured in the azkaban-web-server azkaban.properties. You can do this by checking the **-Dexecutorport** argument to the running azkaban-exec-server process or by checking the **executor.port** value in the azkaban-exec-server azkaban.properties.
If this value differs from the **executor.port** value in the azkaban-web-server azkaban.properties then you need to ensure that the values match (either by modifying executor.port in the azkaban-web-server or azkaban-exec-server azkaban.properties) and that the relevant service(s) get restarted following any configuration changes.